# How to run uiautomatorviewer since Tools became obsolete?

Tags: android

`uiautomatorviewer` used to be in the "sdk\tools" directory of Android SDK. Recently, SDK Tools was marked as obsolete and is not installed or even visible by default. I noticed this on a fresh new installation of Android Studio / Android SDK, as the "tools" directory is not there any more. Originally I was looking for `avdmanager` which also used to be in the same directory; I got it back by installing "Android SDK Command-line Tools", which creates a "cmdline-tools" directory with `avdmanager` inside. But this still didn't bring back `uiautomatorviewer` (unsurprisingly, as the latter is not a command-line tool).

Other than just installing the SDK Tools (ignoring the fact that it's marked obsolete), is there a "proper" way to still be able to launch `uiautomatorviewer`?